# drawing current from multiple sources in parallel

Tags: batteries, current, current-measurement, parallel

I'm working on a project which consists of repurposed training bike to generate electricity. We have 8 bikes connected in parallel to a battery. The bikes are equiped with AC motors and a diode bridge to convert to DC and produce a tension around 24v.

I would like to measure the current produced by each bike separately. I already did it with one bike, but I wonder if it is posible to do the same with multiple DC sources in parallel. Won't I read basically the same measurement on each source ?

Comment: How do you stop bikes that are not in use absorbing current? If there are blocking diodes then you can add a current sensor to to each output with the sensor the bike-side of the blocking diode.

Comment: Good question! As I said I have a diode bridge after each motor for the AC/DC conversion. Won't this act as a blocking diode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do what you are thinking each bike would need it's own current harvester circuit, something like is shown below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqEjzb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**NOTE: The above is concept only and not intended to be a functional design.**

Each bike would have it's own rectifier and a switched inductor. The MOSFET builds current in the inductor when turned on, and when it turns off the voltage on the right side of the inductor rises to a diode drop over whatever voltage is stored on C1 feeding current to the capacitor and charging it up.

The comparator on the right is some sort of control circuit intended to shut off the clock when the voltage on C1 exceeds some maximum value.

You then can use whatever charge is stored on the capacitor to drive a buck-boost regulator to create your final desired voltage.

You can then use individual current meters on each bike and each bike will contribute to the total power available.

***Note however, the load on the riders will drop off markedly when the voltage on C1 exceeds the limit. This will happen if the electrical load on the output is small. That may be a rather dangerous shock to the riders muscles.***

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Well, I must say this is way beyond my current electronics skill. Right now all we have is a bridge on each bike and the outputs are fed directly to the batteries - and it seems to work... So all the parts you added here are solely to be able to read the current on each bike, or is there more to it?

Comment: @tomtom the issue with your current setup is only the strongest rider will be driving the load. Though there is some balancing that happens automatically.

Comment: @tomtom If you just want to read the individual currents. You can ditch the switching part and inductors and just leave in the diodes. But, you will not get maximum power harvesting.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you will only get a current reading from the bike with the highest output Voltage (assuming each bike's current is sensed seperately), all other bikes will contribute zero (or close) current.

In reality the current will most likely split in some way because the output voltage of the bike contributing the hihest current will collaps the most.

For battery charging you still should use some kind of charge electronics.
(eg. all bikes feed an intermediate circuit which feeds a buckboost battery charger)